# CSS3 3D Animation - Falling Wall of a Cube

Tags: css, animation, transform

I have an CSS3 3D animation issue. The div with css class `'css3cube-el'` is placed in a container as displayed in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8wvyQ/2/

Now, I want to transform it (this is what happens after 5 seconds delay) so that it looks like a wall falling to the left side.

Similar to this but moved to the left accordingly:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's moving in a strange way (click the jsfiddle link, please). At the end, the bottom side (which is red) is brought to the front of the container.

Any ideas how to change the css class '.css3cube-left-open' which is responsible for this wrong animation? Currently it looks like this (I changed all the values several times but didn't achieve the desired behavior :-():

```
.css3cube-left-open {
    transform: rotateX( 90deg ) translateY( 100px );
    -moz-transform: rotateX( 90deg ) translateY( 100px );
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 90deg ) translateY( 100px );
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: hi, well, that's almost what I wan to have but mirror-inverted and the red border should remain at the same place rather than moving up. I tried to edit the properties but this code doesn't work too :-/     `-webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg)  rotateX( -90deg )  translateZ(150px);`

Comment: Now I almost have what I was looking for but still ... there is need for optimization... `http://jsfiddle.net/cGMCh/1/`. Thank you.

Comment: Check [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). It looks like you need ` 0 100%`

Comment: thank you it works. for some reasons jsfiddle filters the `transform-origin: 'bottom';` property but in my application it's working and the elements bottom edge remains at the place. The solution is: `transform-origin: center bottom 0`.

Comment: You should post it as a solution. It may help other peopel looking to solve the same problem